# Is it unethical to manually review when you're review-banned?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension, banning

I got review-banned a few weeks ago, but I continued to edit, vote on, comment on, and flag posts during the ban. AFAICT a review-ban indicates that you can't tell the difference between high-quality and low-quality posts. So was it unethical for me to keep moderating even though getting banned means that I'm bad at doing that?

Comment: Considering the numbers of robo-reviewers, I think you're okay in the ethics department.

Comment: if you can continue to do that, it means that you still have the right to do so. You're not vote-banned, or edit-banned.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A review ban *usually* just indicates that you're fatigued; that your eyes are glazing over and you're mechanically clicking buttons without really stopping to pay attention. It happens to everyone sooner or later; the ban exists as a reminder to take a break.

I... Highly recommend taking that break. There's no good reason to burn yourself out on this stuff.

That said... Flagging, voting and commenting are *not* review, even as they are actions that can be *taken* in review. If you see a problem while using the site normally, don't ever feel that you can't step up to fix it or at least report it.

Just don't feel like you have to go out of your way to look for problems.

Comment: you can easily get banned with a bad review audit answer as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't think so. You are never banned for one action; it takes multiple failures to get review banned. Of course, if OP was banned manually by a moderator, then yeah, that could ostensibly be from one bad review (though I doubt the moderators would ban after one bad review as well).

Comment: I was (automatically) banned after several failed audits, but ironically, I failed the audits after having hesitated a lot (that was _not_ roboreviewing), and never had the idea to visit the link :) now I'm wiser, not a ban in several months